# Seconds since epoch to LocalDate in Joda

Tags: java, jodatime

How do I convert seconds past the epoch to `LocalDate` in Joda?

e.g.

```
long seconds  = 1468608443L;
? LocalDate.fromSeconds(seconds); // does not exist
```

What does exist is `fromDateFields` and `fromCalendar`.

Is it necessary to convert seconds to one of these two things first?

Alternately I can make an `Instant` with

```
Instant instant = new Instant(seconds * 1000);
```

then try converting that to `Date` or `DateTime` then input to `LocalDate`. Is that the most standard way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to just do

```
LocaleDate ld = new LocaleDate(seconds)
```

According to [documentation](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) this is how it works

Comment: `public LocalDate(long instant)` expects milliseconds so `seconds * 1000` would be the correct parameter

Answer (score 0):

Best method so far:

```
Instant instant = new Instant(seconds * 1000);
LocalDate date = instant.toDateTime(SOME_TIME_ZONE).toLocalDate();
```